# React Bootstrap Cards and CardDeck Components - responsive layout

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm using React Bootstrap and am pulling data from an API using Axios.  I'm trying to display the data from that API in bootstrap Card / CarDeck components. I have most of it working using the code below but I'm having problems with the layout.

I'd like to be able to have the card deck be responsive and show a flexible number of cards per row depending on the screen size.  At the moment if there are lots of items in the response each card is ridiculously thin and can't be viewed.  What is the correct way to do this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CardDeck from "react-bootstrap/CardDeck";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import axios from "axios";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

const CardColumns = () => {
  const [cardInfo, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(cardInfo);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/cards-fvyrn/service/Cards/incoming_webhook/getAllCards"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const renderCard = (card, index) => {
    return (
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={index} className="box">
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" src={card.image} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>
            {index} - {card.manufacturer}
          </Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{card.player}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  };

  return <CardDeck>{cardInfo.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>;
};
export default CardColumns;
```

Answer (score 4):

In the end this is the solution I went with the below. Key I think were:

1. Wrapping the cardDeck in `<Container>` and then wrapping the cards with `<Col className="container-fluid mt-4">`:

`

```
const renderCard = (card, index) => {
return (`
  <Col className="container-fluid mt-4">
    {/* <Card key={index} className="box"> */}
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} key={index} className="box">
      <Card.Header>
        {card.brand} - {card.series}
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={card.front_image} fluid />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>
          {card.player} (#
          {card.card_number.$numberDouble}) {card.variation}
        </Card.Title>
        {/* <Card.Text className="d-flex">{card.player}</Card.Text> */}
        {/* <Card.Text>{card.player}</Card.Text> */}
      </Card.Body>
      <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
        <ListGroupItem>
          Print Run - {card.print_run.$numberDouble}
        </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>Career Stage - {card.career_stage} </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>For Trade - {card.forTrade}</ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
      <Card.Footer className="text-muted">{card.team}</Card.Footer>
    </Card>
  </Col>

  //{/* </Col> */}
);
  };

  return (
<Container>
  <Button variant="primary">Filter By Brand</Button>{" "}
  <Button variant="primary">Filter By Player</Button>{" "}
  <Button variant="primary">Filter By Team</Button>
  <CardDeck>{cardInfo.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>
</Container>
);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions for this issue:

1. Each card should have a `min-width` to ensure that they do not shrink below a certain amount. So instead of `width: "18rem"` try `min-width: "18rem"`. If your CSS is properly set up it should cause other cards to overflow to the next row.
2. You can make use of `media-queries` or grid layout as mentioned to determine how many cards you want to show for various screen types based on their varying widths say see this link [media-query-breakpoints](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp) [react-bootstrap-grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#col-props)
3. Also you can try using CSS flexbox layout, I have an article on this [CSS Flex Box](http://daltonwhyte.com/index.php/2019/02/27/5-important-features-of-css-flexbox/)

Comment: thanks for your time on this question - I'll have a look at those resources :)

Comment: You are welcome, also I noticed you pulled in `Container` component without actually making using of it. As with responsive designs its essential you wrap the `CardDeck` in the `Container` component

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a col-'n' to each card instead of a fix width.

```
...
import { Card, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
...
    <Col md="n"> // n must be your desired width like
        <Card key={index} className="box">
            ...
    </Col>
```

You can see more at: [Bootstrap Card Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#sizing)

Comment: many thanks for this.  It works well but the content within the cards now does not wrap, so if the value of `<Card.Text>{card.player}</Card.Text>` is a long string it stretches the width of the card

Comment: I'm not sure about that but maybe you can use <Card.Text className="d-flex">{card.player}</Card.Text>

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I have posted the answer that worked for me. Thanks for taking the time to help :)